# Solve a total derivative - independent vs. dependent variables

Tags: differential-equations, differentials

I am trying to force mathematica to solve a generally defined function for d lp:

In a reduced version, `w` depends on `l2`, `lp` and `t`. `l2` and `lp` depend on `t`. Furthermore, `w` is constant with respect to `t`. So, I did

```
Solve[Dt[w[l2, lp, t], t] == 0, Dt[lp, t]]
```

which works.

The problem is that the dynamics of `l2` do not depend on `w`, so they can be defined by:

```
l2[t_] := l20*E^(p*t)
```

where l20 is a constant. So, I tried the following:

```
l2[t_] := l20*E^(p*t)
Solve[Dt[w[l2, lp, t], t, Constants -> {l20, p}] == 0, Dt[lp, t]]
```

which did not help. Second try was this one,

```
Solve[Dt[w[l20*E^(p*t), lp, t], t, Constants -> {l20, p}] == 0, Dt[lp, t]]
```

which did not help either.

Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: It might help to make `l2` and `lp` explicitly function of `t`, inside that total derivative: `Solve[Dt[w[l2[t], lp[t], t], t, Constants -> {l20, p}] == 0, 
 Dt[lp[t], t]]`

Comment: It does. Thx. I will male the second question explicit in another question

Answer (score 2):

As Daniel Lichtblau mentioned in comments, it helps to make l2 and lp explicitly function of t, inside that total derivative:

```
l2[t_] := l20*E^(p*t)
Solve[Dt[w[l2[t], lp[t], t], t, Constants -> {l20, p}] == 0, Dt[lp[t], t]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]